# Neo4j webadmin shows shows Labels, Relationships on Left side but does not list Nodes

Tags: neo4j, web-admin

I am using Neo4j 2.1.2 community edition. When I point neo4j to the database I created and login to webadmin, it shows the relationship type and and Labels I created in my code but when i try to fetch the nodes and relationship it does not list any thing.

See the screenshot attached.[image]

I am creating my database using following piece of code.

```
import org.neo4j.graphdb.GraphDatabaseService;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Label;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Node;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Relationship;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.RelationshipType;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Transaction;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory;

public class HelloWorld {

private GraphDatabaseService m_databaseService;
private Node m_firstNode;
private Node m_secondNode;
private Relationship m_relationship;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new HelloWorld().startApplication();
}

private void startApplication() {
    createDatabase();
    createNodesAndrelationship();
    shutDownDB();
}

private void createDatabase() {
    m_databaseService = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase("E:\\ERM\\RoutingData\\neo4j");
}

private void createNodesAndrelationship() {
    Transaction tx = m_databaseService.beginTx();

    try  {

        m_firstNode = m_databaseService.createNode();
        m_firstNode.addLabel(new Label() {

            @Override
            public String name() {
                return "Demo";
            }
        });
        m_firstNode.setProperty("message", "Hello");
        System.out.println("Created First Node.");

        m_secondNode = m_databaseService.createNode();
        m_secondNode.setProperty("message", "world !");
        m_secondNode.addLabel(new Label() {

            @Override
            public String name() {
                return "Demo";
            }
        });
        System.out.println("Created Second Node.");

        m_relationship = m_firstNode.createRelationshipTo(m_secondNode, RelType.KNOWS);
        m_relationship.setProperty("message", "bravo neo4j !");
        System.out.println("Created relationship.");

        tx.success();
    } finally {

        tx.failure();
    }

    System.out.println(m_firstNode.getProperty("message").toString() + " " + m_relationship.getProperty("message") + " " + m_secondNode.getProperty("message"));
}

private void shutDownDB() {
    m_databaseService.shutdown();
    System.out.println("Database shutdown completed.");
}

private static enum RelType implements RelationshipType {
    KNOWS
}
```

}

Please suggest what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are rolling back the transaction rather than committing it.

Replace `tx.failure()` with `tx.close()`.

Also, this line needs to be moved before the `tx.close()` call, to avoid an `org.neo4j.graphdb.NotInTransactionException`:

```
System.out.println(m_firstNode.getProperty("message").toString() + " " + m_relationship.getProperty("message") + " " + m_secondNode.getProperty("message"));
```